# Selecting a Jquery UI tooltip animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a select array and i want to be able to get the current selected item as a string and pass it to `effect`. There are no issues when manually typing the `effect` value such as `effect: 'bounce'`, but when `bounce` is selected from the list and applied as a variable to `effect` it doesn't work.

```
<select>
    <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
</select>
<script>
  const select = document.querySelector("#effect"); // This is the select array
  let selecetedValue = select[select.selectedIndex].value; // This is the selected option string

  $(".tooltip").tooltip({
    show: {
      effect: selecetedValue, // This is where the string is applied(this is the problem)
      delay: 250
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Here is a code snippet from when it isn't working:**

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#effect");
let selecetedValue = "'" + select[select.selectedIndex].value + "'";

$(".tooltip").tooltip({
  show: {
    effect: selecetedValue,
    delay: 250
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:400px; margin:100px auto;">
      <select id="effect">
        <option value="blind">Blind</option>
        <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
        <option value="clip">Clip</option>
        <option value="drop">Drop</option>
        <option value="explode">Explode</option>
        <option value="fade">Fade</option>
        <option value="fold">Fold</option>
        <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
        <option value="puff">Puff</option>
        <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
        <option value="scale">Scale</option>
        <option value="shake">Shake</option>
        <option value="size">Size</option>
        <option value="slide">Slide</option>
        <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
        <option value="myAnimation">My animation</option>
      </select>
      <br /><br />
      <div style="width:100px">Name:</div>
      <input
        id="ime"
        class="tooltip"
        name="ime"
        style="width:200px"
        title="Name"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is a code snippet from how it's supposed to be working:**

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#effect');
let selecetedValue = select[select.selectedIndex].value;

$('.tooltip').tooltip({
    show: {
        effect: 'bounce',
        delay: 250
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:400px; margin:100px auto;">
      <select id="effect">
        <option value="blind">Blind</option>
        <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
        <option value="clip">Clip</option>
        <option value="drop">Drop</option>
        <option value="explode">Explode</option>
        <option value="fade">Fade</option>
        <option value="fold">Fold</option>
        <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
        <option value="puff">Puff</option>
        <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
        <option value="scale">Scale</option>
        <option value="shake">Shake</option>
        <option value="size">Size</option>
        <option value="slide">Slide</option>
        <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
        <option value="myAnimation">My animation</option>
      </select>
      <br /><br />
      <div style="width:100px">Name:</div>
      <input
        id="ime"
        class="tooltip"
        name="ime"
        style="width:200px"
        title="Name"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select value is set only once in your example. If you or the user changes the value, the tool tip never gets updated value.

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {

  var tips = $('.tooltip').tooltip({
    show: {
      effect: 'bounce',
      delay: 250
    }
  });

  var select = $("#effect");
  tips.tooltip("option", "effect", $("option:selected", select).val());

  select.change(function() {
    var val = $("option:selected", select).val()
    tips.tooltip("option", "show", {
      effect: val
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="width:400px; margin:100px auto;">
  <select id="effect">
    <option value="blind">Blind</option>
    <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
    <option value="clip">Clip</option>
    <option value="drop">Drop</option>
    <option value="explode">Explode</option>
    <option value="fade">Fade</option>
    <option value="fold">Fold</option>
    <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
    <option value="puff">Puff</option>
    <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
    <option value="scale">Scale</option>
    <option value="shake">Shake</option>
    <option value="size">Size</option>
    <option value="slide">Slide</option>
    <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
    <option value="myAnimation">My animation</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <div style="width:100px">Name:</div>
  <input id="ime" class="tooltip" name="ime" style="width:200px" title="Name" />
</div>
```